# Запрос работает в MySQL но не работает в SQLite3

Tags: mysql, sqlite3

Есть таблица в SQLite3 (тип поля текстовый)

| value |
| --- |
| 8-10 |
| 3-9 |
| 5 |
| 4-6 |

Есть запрос который хорошо отрабатывает в MySQL

```
SELECT * from Name_of_tabe where 5> substring_index(value,'-',1)  and 5 <substring_index(value,'-',-1) or value=5;
```

Есть запрос который написан в SQLite3 и он выводит пустую таблицу.

```
SELECT * from test where 5>substr(value, '-', length(-value)) and substr(value, length(-value)+1)<5) or value = 5;
```

В чем проблема? что написано не так? Для понимания необходимо фильтром искать в диапазонах значений.

Необходимо что когда я ввожу цифру **5** у меня было три записи 3-9 и 4-6 и 5.

Comment: Может, вам лучше сделать два целочисленных поля start и end?

Comment: Думал над этим, но хотелось бы пока решить проблему таким образом

Comment: *Есть запрос который написан в SQLite3 и он выводит пустую таблицу.* Неправда. Обязан давать syntax error.

Comment: *В чем проблема?* Изучайте: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d24d18250cd82742121a60b6de373de2

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      * 
from 
     test
where
     (
       5 > substr(value, 1, instr(value,'-')-1)+0 and
       5 < substr(value, instr(value,'-')+1, length(value)-1)-0
     ) or  
     value = 5
```